# how to create one to one reference in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a `blog` collection and `category` collection.

Now I am saving `blog document` with category:

```
{
   title: "test",
   categoryName: "misc"
}
```

The category collection has list of categories:

```
categories: 
  [{ categoryName: "misc"}, categoryName: "misc2",...]
```

Now when I save blog document, do I need to push generated `blog._id` into category collection to create `one to one` reference?

Comment: Yes, We can have Mongo DB ref in collection, Please look into this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mongodb-dbref-annotation . But in my understand having the embedded in the document will help you then keeping the reference.

Comment: @GopinathNavaneethan How do I pull blogs based on `categoryName` after the above implementation?